# Not Found: "Navigation.Parser" and "Navigation.makeParser"

Tags: elm

I have the following errors that I am struggling to resolve based on the latest version of elm-lang/Navigation:

> -- NAMING ERROR ------------------------------------------------------- Home.elm
>
> Cannot find variable `Navigation.makeParser`.
>
> 231|     Navigation.makeParser parse
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Navigation` does not expose `makeParser`.
>
> -- NAMING ERROR ------------------------------------------------------- Home.elm
>
> Cannot find type `Navigation.Parser`.
>
> 229| urlParser : Navigation.Parser Route
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Navigation` does not expose `Parser`.

**Note:**

It looks like Parser and makePaser were removed from Navigation in version 2.1.0.

Is there an updated example of how to do navigation leveraging the urlParser function?

I have the following:

```
import Navigation exposing (..)

main : Program Never
main =
    Navigation.program urlParser
        { model = model
        , update = update
        , urlUpdate = urlUpdate
        , view = view
        }

...

-- NAVIGATION


parse : Navigation.Location -> Route
parse { pathname } =
    let
        one =
            Debug.log "path" pathname
    in
        case pathname of
            "index.html" ->
                HomeRoute

            _ ->
                NotFound


urlParser : Navigation.Parser Route
urlParser =
    Navigation.makeParser parse
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Parser` concept was [removed during the Elm 0.18 to simplify the API](https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation/commit/f88927e7dae0b2d0c5ca04e7804c9c3ea17f22c1). Now you just need to supply a function that takes a `Location` and returns a `Msg` as the first parameter to [program](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/2.1.0/Navigation#program) function.

That function could simply be a `Msg` constructor that takes a `Location` argument, as shown in the example from the [examples directory](https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation/tree/2.1.0/examples) (here is [live example on ellie-app.com](https://ellie-app.com/3n6T3NqwR5Fa1/1))

```elm
type Msg
    = UrlChange Navigation.Location
```

Your `update` function would then handle the `UrlChange` `Msg` and act accordingly. You can still use `Location` parsing packages like [evancz/url-parser](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/url-parser/latest).